# Identifying maximum number and longest set of time intervals

Tags: r

Say I have data that look like this:

```
   level   start     end
1      1 133.631 825.141
2      2 133.631 155.953
3      3 146.844 155.953
4      2 293.754 302.196
5      3 293.754 302.196
6      4 293.754 301.428
7      2 326.253 343.436
8      3 326.253 343.436
9      4 333.827 343.436
10     2 578.066 611.766
11     3 578.066 611.766
12     4 578.066 587.876
13     4 598.052 611.766
14     2 811.228 825.141
15     3 811.228 825.141
```

or this:

```
   level      start        end
1      1    3.60353 1112.62000
2      2    3.60353   20.35330
3      3    3.60353    8.77526
4      2   72.03720  143.60700
5      3   73.50530  101.13200
6      4   73.50530   81.64660
7      4   92.19030  101.13200
8      3  121.28500  143.60700
9      4  121.28500  128.25900
10     2  167.19700  185.04800
11     3  167.19700  183.44600
12     4  167.19700  182.84600
13     2  398.12300  418.64300
14     3  398.12300  418.64300
15     2  445.83600  454.54500
16     2  776.59400  798.34800
17     3  776.59400  796.64700
18     4  776.59400  795.91300
19     2  906.68800  915.89700
20     3  906.68800  915.89700
21     2 1099.44000 1112.62000
22     3 1099.44000 1112.62000
23     4 1100.14000 1112.62000
```

They produce the following graphs:

[image]

As you can see there are several time intervals at different levels. The level-1 interval always spans the entire duration of the time of interest.  Levels 2+ have time intervals that are shorter.

What I would like to do is select the maximum number of non-overlapping time intervals covering each period that contain the maximum number of total time within them.  I have marked in pink which ones those would be.

For small dataframes it is possible to brute force this, but obviously there should be some more logical way of doing this. I'm interested in hearing some ideas about what I should try.

EDIT:

I think one thing that could help here is the column 'level'. The results come from Kleinberg's burst detection algorithm (package 'bursts'). You will note that the levels are hierarchically organized. Levels of the same number cannot overlap.  However levels successively increasing e.g. 2,3,4 in successive rows can overlap.

In essence, I think the problem could be shortened to this. Take the levels produced, but remove level 1. This would be the vector for the 2nd example:

```
 2 3 2 3 4 4 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 2 2 3 4 2 3 2 3 4
```

Then, look at the 2s... if there are fewer than or only one '3' then that 2 is the longest interval. But if there are two or more 3's between successive 2's, then those 3s should be counted. Do this iteratively for each level. I think that should work...?

e.g.

```
vec<-df$level %>% as.vector() %>% .[-1]
vec
#[1] 2 3 2 3 4 4 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 2 2 3 4 2 3 2 3 4

max(vec) #4
vec3<-vec #need to find two or more 4's between 3s
vec3[vec3==3]<-NA  
names(vec3)<-cumsum(is.na(vec3))

 0  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  4  5  5  5  6  6  6  7  7  8  8 
 2 NA  2 NA  4  4 NA  4  2 NA  4  2 NA  2  2 NA  4  2 NA  2 NA  4 

vec3.res<-which(table(vec3,names(vec3))["4",]>1)
which(names(vec3)==names(vec3.res) & vec3==4) #5 6
```

The above identifies rows 5 and 6 (which equate to rows 6 and 7 in original df) as having two  fours that lie between 3's.   Perhaps something using this sort of approach might work?

Comment: The rules are a bit ambiguous. Number of intervals is more important than total time? I.e., in the first example, why select the two short intervals at 600 and not the one longer interval.

Comment: I don't have time to write the code, but my idea would be to use `foverlaps` from package data.table with `type = "within"` to compare each level with the next and take the intervals from the higher level if there are more than one match for the resp. interval from the lower level.

Comment: @Roland thanks- the first tie-breaker is number of intervals. The solution should have the maximum possible intervals.  After that, the next tie-breaker is total time.   If the first tie-breaker were total time then we would just take the interval at  level1.!

Comment: This is an interesting question. It seems to have the flavor of [string searching algorithms](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec18-extra.pdf). In general can you start with the level 4 set of intervals as your "guess," and then iteratively pass through each interval by falling down a level if the next level's container doesn't contain an additional interval. By the way does a lower-level interval ever *partially* contain a higher-level interval? If not I think you can reduce the iterative check to comparing the right endpoint at one level to the next at the higher level.

Comment: Also can you please explain your "look at the 2s and 3s" algorithm a little more?

Comment: @Philip the  idea is to find the highest level in the data - in the example it's 4, but it could be higher.  Then, check the level before that (3) and examine if two instances of level 4 exist between any pair of 3s. If they do, that must mean that those two 4s could be included rather than the first 3.  This can be completed all the way down to level 2 - there's no point doing level 1 as it always just  spans the entire time period.   Does  this make sense? I could draw it out as a hierarchical tree.

Comment: I think this is consistent with the approach in my answer. Can you test out the algorithm I wrote (with the modification to use `lapply` so it works on an arbitrary number of levels) on some more examples for which you know the outcomes, and see if it works? Offhand, I'd guess you'll find some cases it fails, but I think the overall logic might be close enough that modifying it to handle those cases could be fairly straightforward. You can also probably find ways to optimize the algorithm; at the moment it favors clarity over speed, as your example tables are fairly small.

Comment: @Philip thanks - I will try with more examples. I think the highest level I have in the data is 6 with 100 rows. I will let you know how your solution works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is a stab using your second data set to test. This might not be correct in all cases!!

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("data.csv")
dat[,use:="maybe"]
make.pass <- function(dat,low,high,the.level,use)  {
    check <- dat[(use!="no" & level > the.level)]
    check[,contained.by.above:=(low<=start & end<=high)]
    check[,consecutive.contained.by.above:=
          (contained.by.above & 
           !is.na(shift(contained.by.above,1)) & 
           shift(contained.by.above,1)),by=level]
    if(!any(check[,consecutive.contained.by.above])) {
        #Cause a side effect where we've learned we don't care:
        dat[check[(contained.by.above),rownum],use:="no"]
        print(check)
        return("yes")
    } else {
        return("no")
    }
}
dat[,rownum:=.I]
dat[level==1,use:=make.pass(dat,start,end,level,use),by=rownum]
dat
dat[use=="maybe" & level==2,use:=make.pass(dat,start,end,level,use),by=rownum]
dat
dat[use=="maybe" & level==3,use:=make.pass(dat,start,end,level,use),by=rownum]
dat
#Finally correct for last level
dat[use=="maybe" & level==4,use:="yes"]
```

I wrote these last steps out so you can trace in your own interactive session to see what's happening (see the print to get an idea) but you can remove the print and also condense the last steps into something like `lapply(1:dat[,max(level)-1], function(the.level) dat[use=="maybe" & level==the.level,use:=make.pass......])` **In response to your comment** if there are an arbitrary number of levels you will definitely want to use this formalism, and follow it with a final call to `dat[use=="maybe" & level==max(level),use:="yes"]`.

Output:

```
> dat
    level      start        end use rownum
 1:     1    3.60353 1112.62000  no      1
 2:     2    3.60353   20.35330 yes      2
 3:     3    3.60353    8.77526  no      3
 4:     2   72.03720  143.60700  no      4
 5:     3   73.50530  101.13200  no      5
 6:     4   73.50530   81.64660 yes      6
 7:     4   92.19030  101.13200 yes      7
 8:     3  121.28500  143.60700 yes      8
 9:     4  121.28500  128.25900  no      9
10:     2  167.19700  185.04800 yes     10
11:     3  167.19700  183.44600  no     11
12:     4  167.19700  182.84600  no     12
13:     2  398.12300  418.64300 yes     13
14:     3  398.12300  418.64300  no     14
15:     2  445.83600  454.54500 yes     15
16:     2  776.59400  798.34800 yes     16
17:     3  776.59400  796.64700  no     17
18:     4  776.59400  795.91300  no     18
19:     2  906.68800  915.89700 yes     19
20:     3  906.68800  915.89700  no     20
21:     2 1099.44000 1112.62000 yes     21
22:     3 1099.44000 1112.62000  no     22
23:     4 1100.14000 1112.62000  no     23
    level      start        end use rownum
```

On the off chance this is correct, the algorithm can roughly be described as follows:

1. Mark all the intervals as possible.
2. Start with a given level. Pick a particular interval (`by=rownum`) say called **X**. With **X** in mind, subset a copy of the data to all higher-level intervals.
3. Mark any of these that are contained in **X** as "contained in **X**".
4. If consecutive intervals at the same level are contained in **X**, **X** is no good b/c it wastes intervals. In this case label **X**'s "use" variable as "no" so we'll never think about **X** again. [*Note*: if it's possible that non-consecutive intervals are contained in **X**, or that containing multiple intervals across levels could ruin **X**'s viability, then this logic might need to be changed to count contained intervals instead of finding consecutive ones. I didn't think about this at all, but it's just occurring to me now, so use at your own risk.]
5. On the other hand, if **X** passed the test, then we've already established it's good. Mark it as a "yes." But *importantly*, we also have to mark any single interval contained in **X** as "no," or else when we iterate the step it will forget that it was contained inside a good interval and mark itself as "yes" as well. This is the side effect step.
6. Now, iterate, ignoring any results that we've already determined.
7. Finally any "maybe"s leftover at the highest level are automatically in.

Let me know what you think of this--this is a rough draft and some aspects might not be correct.

Comment: with specific regard to point 4 - I don't think it is possible that multiple intervals can overlap a lower level interval.  i.e. if there is a level 2 between e.g. 10 and 20, then all levels 3/4/5 must be bounded by at least 10 and most 20 within that level.  I think this answers your point?

Comment: also if what you mean by 'non-consecutive' is that maybe other intervals would be not arranged in time order, then I think all intervals will be.  I will double check this method against a batch of sample results tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, that is the concern. My "consecutive" just checks a row against shifting that row by 1 position, but if the intervals aren't ordered correctly then that's not the right test for "contains two or more intervals." An easy way to nullify the issue is to `setkey(dat,start,level,end)` or another keying (which sorts the `data.table`). It looks as though your table is sorted at least in that order for the first two variables (by `start`, then by `level` where `start` matches).

Comment: Did you ever test this?

Comment: sorry didn't have time yet- will do this pm.  I think it looks like it should work - will get back to you

Comment: No worries. Looking forward to seeing results and happy to try to modify it if it fails on some cases. Best

Comment: Yes - this seems to work, at least when the max level is 4.  It turns out that the maximum level I get in my data is '7'.  I'm trying to turn this into a function to apply to any df as in the example, but get it to apply the `make.pass` function up to the final level automatically - any ideas on this? - thanks again, great help.

Comment: I think I've solved this level issue by making the function operate in a loop over ever level up to the penultimate level, and then adding the final pass over the `max(dat$level)`- thanks